# Ruby convert Array of Arrays to Tree Structure

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, nested

I have an array of arrays like this

```
[['Europe', 'UK', 'London'], ['Europe', 'UK', 'Bristol'], ['Europe', 'France']]
```

And I'm wanting to convert it so I have a Nested Hash structure something like this:

```
{"Europe"=>{"UK"=>["London", "Bristol"], "France"=>[]}}
```

I also want it to be generated recursively so the number of elements in each array is not limited.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Result must be a Hash or nested Arrays?

Comment: It doesn't really matter

Comment: For implementation it really matters )

Comment: Your result is just some lines of text, please provide a valid Ruby structure.

Comment: A nested array would be good

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start from something like that:

```
arr = [['Europe', 'UK', 'London'], ['Europe', 'UK', 'Bristol'], ['Europe', 'France']]

arr.each.with_object({}) do |(region, country, city), hsh|
  hsh[region] ||= {}
  hsh[region][country] ||= []
  hsh[region][country] << city if city
end

# => {"Europe"=>{"UK"=>["London", "Bristol"], "France"=>[]}}
```

Some improvements:

```
arr.each.with_object({}) do |args, hsh|
  target = hsh
  args.each { |key| target = target[key] ||= {} }
end
# => {"Europe"=>{"UK"=>{"London"=>{}, "Bristol"=>{}}, "France"=>{}}}
```

Comment: The number of elements in each array is not limited to three however I want it to be able to handle any number of elements

Comment: Perfect. Thankyou for your help

Comment: You are wellcome, @Joe!

Comment: For this structure you can use `hsh = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }` insted of `each_with_object `method.

Comment: Solution with Hash#default_proc looks not so readable to me. @Lukas, post your implementation so we can compare.